# PHP Issue Iterating Over Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have two arrays $patients and $escorts.

These arrays represent hospital stays for various patients and escorts.
Escorts have a ['Escort']['id'] value that is associated with the ID of a Guest (Patient).

My goal is two take the Patients and Escorts arrays and combine them into a results array that can be used for printing (either a table, or creating an excel file).

Patients may have multiple stays, and a Patient may also have multiple Escorts escorting them.

```
$patients = [
     Patient A,
     Patient B,
     Patient B
     Patient C,
     Patient D,
     Patient E
 ];

 $escorts = [
     Escort for Patient B,
     Escort 1 for Patient C,
     Escort 2 for Patient C,
     Escort for Patient E 
 ];
```

I am trying to get the $newResults array in the following order:

```
$newResults = [
   Patient A,
   Patient B,
   Patient B,
   Escort for Patient B,
   Patient C,
   Escort for Patient C,
   Escort for Patient C,
   Patient D,
   Patient E,
   Escort for Patient E,
]
```

However, when I'm done iterating through both arrays I have leftover $escort elements that haven't been added after their $patient counterpart, yet going through the data the Patient's ['Guests']['id'] and the Escort's ['Escort']['id'] match, so I'm not sure why they're not being included.

The code I am using is:

```
 $lastPatientID = 0;
 foreach($patients as $pkey => $patient) {
    if($lastPatientID == 0) {
        $lastPatientID = $patient['Guests']['id'];
    }

    if($patient['Guests']['id'] == $lastPatientID) {
        // Add Patients Next Accommodation
        $newResults[] = $patient;
    } else {
        $theseEscorts = [];

        foreach($escorts as $ekey => $escort) {
            if($escort['Escort']['id'] == $lastPatientID) {
                $theseEscorts[] = $escort;
                unset($escorts[$ekey]);
            }
        }

        // Print the escorts for the Last Patient.
        foreach($theseEscorts as $anEscort) {
            $newResults[] = $anEscort;
        }

        // This Patient is different than last. Print New Patient.
        $newResults[] = $patient;
    }

    $lastPatientID = $patient['Guests']['id'];
}

// Clear any remaining escorts that match the last patient.
foreach($escorts as $escort) {
     if($escort['Escort']['id'] == $lastPatientID) {
         $newResults[] = $escort;
     } else {
          // NOTE:: THIS SHOULDN'T HAPPEN UNLESS DATA IS BAD!
          error_log("Orphaned Escort: \n" . print_r($escort, TRUE) );
     }
 }
```

I must be making some logic mistake with this, although I'm not sure where.

Any advice is much apprecaited!

Comment: Please go to https://3v4l.org/ and put your sample array and code then hit "Eval" and post the link here.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/QOEco

As you can see in the Output for 5.4.0

The resulting $newResults array is ordered:

0 - Jane Smith
1 - John Smith
2 - Jane Doe

This is as it should be. But in some instances (and I'm not sure what's causing it so I can't reproduce it) the results would be:

0 - Jane Smith
1 - Jane Doe 

(John Smith isn't getting added)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from what you've given here.  We discussed this on IRC and I proposed this solution given the actual structure of your arrays.

Features:

- Each line in the result array is either one patient or one escort for that patient
- The type will tell you which it is
- The rec will give you all the rest of the information
- Building the escortMap ensures you don't have to loop through all the escorts for each patient.

```
$escorts = [];

$newResults = [];

$escortMap = [];

foreach($escorts as $escortId => $e){
    $escortMap[$e->Escort->id][] = $escortId;
}

foreach( $patients as $patientId => $p ){

    $newResults[] = array(
        'type' => 'patient',
        'rec' => $p
    );

    foreach( $escortMap[$patientId] as $escortId){
        $e = $escorts[$escortId];
        if($e->Escort->id == $patient->Guest->id){ // or some other test to see if this escort matches this patient
            $newResults[] = array(
                'type' => 'escort for ' . $patientId,
                'rec' => $e
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution to this. The cause of the problem was some bad data, instances where the Escort was associated with a Patient who didn't have an entry in the database table for accommodations.

My solution to this was to implement a uasort() function to put the rows I wanted in the correct order:

```
uasort($newResults, function($a, $b) {
    $aSortOn = ($a['Accommodations']['purpose_id'] != 4 ? $a['Guests']['lastName'] : $a['Escort']['lastName']);
    $bSortOn = ($b['Accommodations']['purpose_id'] != 4 ? $b['Guests']['lastName'] : $b['Escort']['lastName']);

    if($aSortOn == $bSortOn) {
        $aSortOn = ($a['Accommodations']['purpose_id'] != 4 ? $a['Guests']['firstName'] : $a['Escort']['firstName']);
        $bSortOn = ($b['Accommodations']['purpose_id'] != 4 ? $b['Guests']['firstName'] : $b['Escort']['firstName']);
    }

    if($aSortOn == $bSortOn) {
        // Sort to Make Sure Patient (Purpose_id != 4) is above (Purpose_id == 4) in results.
        if($a['Accommodations']['purpose_id'] != 4 && $b['Accommodations']['purpose_id'] == 4) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }

    } else {
        return ($aSortOn < $bSortOn) ? -1 : 1;
    }
});
```

If the guest is a Patient, it will sort them by LastName, FirstName, and if they are an Escort it sorts them by the LastName, FirstName of the person they are escorting.